# JB adds Subscriberkey and EmailAddress

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have noticed that as soon as I save an interaction in Journey Builder, SFMC automatically adds SubscriberKey and EmailAddress fields to the Event Source DE (even when I already have an email address field)

Am I supposed to use these auto generated fields then? Or Can I just ignore these? Is there a way to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

These fields are reserved for system use. I would not recommend removing them or populating values into these fields as this may result in unexpected behavior. I'm not exactly sure what they are used for as there is no documentation on this.

Also note that when creating Event Source Data Extensions, you should avoid creating fields named 'SubscriberKey' and 'EmailAddress' as this will result in issues (I've experienced this before).

Answer (score 1):

This is a confirmed bug. The downside is if you have a separate email address field (from salesforce for example) the addition of these fields by the triggered send in the journey will break the ability to use the data extension for sending test emails. No idea if it will be fixed?

Comment: Is this confirmed by Salesforce you mean?

Comment: Yes, confirmed by salesforce.